# Can I use KeyGenerator if encryptor and decryptor are in different application/server

Tags: encryption, base64, aes, secret-key

I am working with encryption using AES. My customer is encrypting some of the sensitive data while posting the data to my web API. And my code will decrypt these fields before insert them to the database.

Originally we agree to use a fixed secret key. Below is the code:

```
public class AESEncryptor {
    private static final String ALGO = "AES";
    private static final String keyVal = "!5Po4@j82Adsu39/*na3n5";

    public static String encrypt(String data) {
        try {
            Key key = genKey();
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(data.getBytes());
            return Base64.encodeBase64String(encVal);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt (String encryptedData) throws Exception{
        Key key = genKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedData);
        byte[] decByptes = c.doFinal(data);
        return new String(decByptes);
    }

    private static Key genKey() throws Exception {
        fixKeyLength();
        return new SecretKeySpec(keyVal.getBytes(), ALGO);
    }
}
```

Then the other party suggested we should switch to `KeyGenerator` to generate a random secure key. Something like the following.

```
      KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
      keyGen.init(256);
      SecretKey key = keyGen.generateKey();

      final byte[] nonce = new byte[32];
      SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
      random.nextBytes(nonce);
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
      GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(16 * 8, nonce);
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
```

I am not sure that is possible. Because the correct decryption relies on the same key for encryption. If the key is random, how would my API know what key to use every time? Or is there a solution to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution to handle this problem.  Symmetric encryption requires that both parties know the key in order to encrypt and decrypt.  If the key is random each time, then you need a way to communicate the key.

The scheme you have designed is quite poor, since a fixed key means that the key being compromised will bring down the whole system.  You're also using ECB mode, which is inherently insecure.  No authentication either.

If you want to communicate data securely from one party to another, use TLS with client authentication.  This is the industry standard way to solve this problem and you don't have to get your hands dirty with the crypto.